# Azure function parameter from settings.json file

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I have the following  azure function

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic-bus", "sub-bus", Connection = "myCString")] string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("test123");
    }
```

I also have the following settings.json file

```
"Values":{
    myTopic: "topic-bus",
    mySub: "sub-bus"
}
```

I don't want to use "topic-bus" and "sub-bus" string as part of the Run parameter. I would like to get those string from my settings.json file. Is ther eanyway to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way:

```
[ServiceBusTrigger("%myTopic%", "%mySub%", Connection = "myCString")]
```